# Delete successive 2 rows if two columns have different values [Panda]

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a df as follow:

```
A    B    C
45   0    0
40   0    1    
43   1    1
49   1    1
45   1    1
40   1    0
43   0    0
47   0    0
48   0    0
51   0    0
```

I want to iterate through the df, check columns A and B.

1. If A==B, delete the next two rows.
2. Repeat step-1 till length of df.

The final output should look like.

```
A    B    C
45   0    0
40   0    1 (two successive rows will be deleted)
45   1    1
40   1    0 (two successive rows will be deleted)
48   0    0
51   0    0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first compare `B` with `C` and then double [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) boolean mask, last invert with `~` and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
m = df['B'] != df['C']
df = df[~(m.shift(1) | m.shift(2))]
print (df)
    A  B  C
0  45  0  0
1  40  0  1
4  45  1  1
5  40  1  0
8  48  0  0
9  51  0  0
```

Comment: I tried it and it worked for the given df, However when I am applying it on my original data, where I want to skip 10 rows by adding data[~(m.shift(1) | m.shift(10))]. It seems its not deleting 10 rows. I am further investigating the exact issue. Please bear with me till I find the reason.

Comment: Secondly I have actually data as numpy array which I converted to dataframe to apply your solution and convert the output back to np.array. If you have alternate solution for np.array, that will be appreciated.

Comment: To first comment - unfortunately need `~(m.shift(1) | m.shift(2) | m.shift(3) | m.shift(4)...)` to `10`, so try fint another solution.

Comment: Yeah, The method ~(m.shift(1) | m.shift(2) | m.shift(3) | m.shift(4)...) worked... Thanks